# Date inserted by Emacs org-mode is not readable

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org-mode within Emacs.

The problem is after issuing `C-c >` or `C-c .`
org-mode insert date like below,

(firstly it appears within the minibuffer,  even the editing file is encoded with utf-8)

<2012-12-09 \326\334\310\325>

How to resolve this issue? My OS is Win7 32bit Chinese version.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, I think the *fonts* emacs is using are not able to display the way the day is spelled in your language. I'd guess you lack some installed fonts, or emacs doesn't know where to find them, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

That being said, inserting such octal escapes into my emacs gives me `ÖÜÈÕ`, which I don't believe to be how days spell in many languages. The file might be encoded in utf-8, but what about the buffer ? What's the `buffer-file-coding-system` variable in that buffer (<kbd>C-h v</kbd> `buffer-file-coding-system`) ?

The variables `calendar-day-name-array` and `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` might be of interest, and I guess you could override how the timestamps appear right now with `org-display-custom-times`, that would probably be a workaround. See [the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html#Custom-time-format) for more about it.

At last, I have

```
  (set-language-environment "UTF-8")
  (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

in my config, functions you may want to investigate about.

Comment: Thanks for reply. my buffer-file-coding-system is utf-8. also it can edit/display chinese characers normaly. 

calendar-day-name-array is a variable defined in `calendar.el'.

Its value is
["Sunday" "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday"]


org-time-stamp-custom-formats is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is ("<%m/%d/%y %a>" . "<%m/%d/%y %a %H:%M>")

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much more. If you really want something to work, I suggest you to `org-display-custom-times` over the glitch, but I rather hope you find a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem to yours.

Through a long time searching online, I found `(setq system-time-locale "C")` work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to fix this problem in August, 2014.

My solution is adding the following code into your Emacs config file:

`(set-locale-environment "zh_CN.utf-8")`

Note that the time will be displayed in Chinese. Hope it helps.